# Where can one find screenshots or demos of Drupal modules?

Tags: drupal, plugins, drupal-modules

I often find myself searching for a Drupal module for a particular purpose on [drupal.org/project/modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules). However, the descriptions there give very little information about the end user experience. One module I recently looked up is [Related Links](http://drupal.org/project/relatedlinks). The description sounds as though it does what I want, but I have to wireframe a site using it, and I have no idea what the UI is like.

Is there a good central source for screenshots or demos of Drupal modules?

Comment: You might be interested in Drupal Answers http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NOT a central repository of Drupal module demos. Sometimes the module author will setup a demo site. Look on the project's page (on Drupal.org) in the right sidebar under "Resources". Sometimes there is a link "Try out a demonstration" or "Read documentation". If it isn't there, then you will need to try installing the module yourself or search the Internet for documentation or examples.

Comment: if only module authors took screenshots at least! WordPress plugins will usually have screenshots at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Comment: @Mike - Yeah, it can be frustrating. I have found it useful to have a test Drupal installation that I use to try out modules.